# Termination check on unionWith

Tags: termination, agda

I'm having a problem with termination checking, very similar to the one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910737/termination-check-on-list-merge) and also this [Agda bug report/feature request](https://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/detail?id=59).

The problem is convincing the compiler that the following `unionWith` terminates. Using a combining function for duplicate keys, `unionWith` merges two maps represented as lists of (key, value) pairs sorted by key. The Key parameter of a finite map is a (non-tight) lower bound on the keys contained in the map. (One reason for defining this data type is to provide a semantic domain into which I can interpret AVL trees in order to prove various properties about them.)

```
open import Function
open import Relation.Binary renaming (IsEquivalence to IsEq)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as P using (_≡_)

module FiniteMap
   {k v ℓ ℓ′}
   {Key : Set k}
   (Value : Set v)
   {_<_ : Rel Key ℓ}
   (isStrictTotalOrder : IsStrictTotalOrder _≡_ _<_)
   {_≈_ : Rel Value ℓ′}
   (isEquivalence : IsEq _≈_)
   where

   open import Algebra.FunctionProperties
   open import Data.Product
   open IsStrictTotalOrder isStrictTotalOrder
   open import Level

   KV : Set (k ⊔ v)
   KV = Key × Value

   data FiniteMap (l : Key) : Set (k ⊔ v ⊔ ℓ) where
      [] : FiniteMap l
      _∷_ : (kv : KV) → let k = proj₁ kv in l < k → (m : FiniteMap k) → FiniteMap l

   unionWith : ∀ {l} → Op₂ Value → Op₂ (FiniteMap l)
   unionWith _ [] [] = []
   unionWith _ [] m = m
   unionWith _ m [] = m
   unionWith _⊕_ (_∷_ (k , v) k<l m) (_∷_ (k′ , v′) k′<l m′) with compare k k′
   ... | tri< k<k′ _ _ = _∷_ (k , v) k<l (unionWith _⊕_ m (_∷_ (k′ , v′) k<k′ m′))
   ... | tri≈ _ k≡k′ _ rewrite P.sym k≡k′ = {!!} --_∷_ (k , v ⊕ v′) k<l (unionWith _⊕_ m m′)
   ... | tri> _ _ k′<k = _∷_ (k′ , v′) k′<l (unionWith _⊕_ (_∷_ (k , v) k′<k m) m′)
```

I've been unable to generalise the solutions discussed in the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910737/termination-check-on-list-merge)  to my setting. For example if I introduce an auxiliary function `unionWith'`, defined mutually recursively with `unionWith`, which is invoked from the latter in the `k' < k` case:

```
   unionWith : ∀ {l} → Op₂ Value → Op₂ (FiniteMap l)
   unionWith′ : ∀ {l} → Op₂ Value → (kv : KV) → let k = proj₁ kv in l < k → FiniteMap k → Op₁ (FiniteMap l)

   unionWith _ [] [] = []
   unionWith _ [] m = m
   unionWith _ m [] = m
   unionWith _⊕_ (_∷_ (k , v) k<l m) (_∷_ (k′ , v′) k′<l m′) with compare k k′
   ... | tri< k<k′ _ _ = _∷_ (k , v) k<l (unionWith _⊕_ m (_∷_ (k′ , v′) k<k′ m′))
   ... | tri≈ _ k≡k′ _ rewrite P.sym k≡k′ = {!!} --_∷_ (k , v ⊕ v′) k<l (unionWith _⊕_ m m′)
   ... | tri> _ _ k′<k = _∷_ (k′ , v′) k′<l (unionWith′ _⊕_ (k , v) k′<k m m′)

   unionWith′ _ (k , v) l<k m [] = _∷_ (k , v) l<k m
   unionWith′ _⊕_ (k , v) l<k m (_∷_ (k′ , v′) k′<l m′) with compare k k′
   ... | tri< k<k′ _ _ = {!!}
   ... | tri≈ _ k≡k′ _ = {!!}
   ... | tri> _ _ k′<k = _∷_ (k′ , v′) k′<l (unionWith′ _⊕_ (k , v) k′<k m m′)
```

then as soon as I tie the recursive knot by replacing the first missing case in `unionWith'` with the required call to `unionWith`, it fails to termination-check.

I also tried introducing additional `with` patterns, but that's complicated by need to use the result of `compare` in the recursive calls. (If I use nested `with` clauses that doesn't seem to help the termination checker.)

Is there a way to use `with` patterns or auxiliary functions to get this compiling? It seems like a straightforward enough situation, so I'm hoping it just a case of knowing the right trick.

(Maybe the new termination checker in the Agda development branch can deal with this, but I'd like to avoid installing a development version unless I have to.)

Comment: Can you check the second version (`unionWith′`) with `{-# OPTIONS --termination-depth=2 #-}` at the top of the file? I think it should work, but I want to be sure before I write an answer.

Comment: Hmm. In between posting this question and reading your response, I upgraded to Agda 2.3.3. Now the `unionWith'` solution seems to work, without any explicit setting of `--termination-depth`. I'll post that as an answer for future reference. Unfortunately, it's not easy for me to roll back to 2.3.2, so I can't conduct your `--termination-depth=2` experiment. Sorry about that (especially as I said that I wanted to avoid installing a development version).

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the second solution works in the development version. New features in 2.3.3 made `--termination-depth` useless; it's now enabled "by default" (the termination checker works as if `--termination-depth=infinity`, if I understood the release notes correctly), so my first instinct was to try explicitly setting `--termination-depth` in earlier version. I had a development version from November, which I think doesn't have the new algorithm, and it seems to work there.

Comment: I did actually experiment with `--termination-depth` in 2.3.2, but not set to 2. I did try some bigger numbers though (20) and it didn't help. I got briefly excited when I tried 1000 and it looked like everything was passing, before I realised the termination checker itself hadn't terminated. (Well, I guess it might have done eventually...)

Comment: Well, `--termination-depth=20` should do everything `--termination-depth=2` does and more, so the (older) version I tried already had more clever termination checker. Never mind. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative based on sized types, based on [the answer to this later question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512464/termination-checking-of-function-over-a-trie). You can pick up the `Data.Extended-key` module from here, or you can tweak the code below so that it uses `Data.AVL.Extended-key` from the standard library instead.

Preamble:

```
{-# OPTIONS --sized-types #-}

open import Relation.Binary renaming (IsStrictTotalOrder to IsSTO)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as P using (_≡_)

-- A list of (key, value) pairs, sorted by key in strictly descending order.
module Temp
   {  ℓ}
   {Key : Set }
   (Value : Key → Set )
   {_<_ : Rel Key ℓ}
   (isStrictTotalOrder′ : IsSTO _≡_ _<_)
   where

   open import Algebra.FunctionProperties
   open import Data.Extended-key isStrictTotalOrder′
   open import Function
   open import Level
   open import Size
   open IsStrictTotalOrder isStrictTotalOrder
```

Now the `FiniteMap` definition, augmented with size indices.

```
   data FiniteMap (l u : Key⁺) : {ι : Size} → Set ( ⊔  ⊔ ℓ) where
      [] : {ι : _} → .(l <⁺ u) → FiniteMap l u {↑ ι}
      _↦_∷[_]_ : {ι : _} (k : Key) (v : Value k) → .(l <⁺ [ k ]) → 
                 (m : FiniteMap [ k ] u {ι}) → FiniteMap l u {↑ ι}

   infixr 3 _↦_∷[_]_
```

Then we can write a version `unionWith` that termination-checks, without cheesing around with auxiliary functions.

```
   unionWith : ∀ {l u} → (∀ {k} → Op₂ (Value k)) →
               {ι : Size} → FiniteMap l u {ι} → {ι′ : Size} → 
               FiniteMap l u {ι′} → FiniteMap l u
   unionWith _ ([] l<⁺u) ([] _) = [] l<⁺u
   unionWith _ ([] _) m = promote m
   unionWith _ m ([] _ )= promote m
   unionWith ∙ (k ↦ v ∷[ _ ] m) (k′ ↦ v′ ∷[ _ ] m′) with compare [ k ] [ k′ ]
   ... | (tri< k<⁺k′ _ _) = k ↦ v ∷[ _ ] unionWith ∙ m (k′ ↦ v′ ∷[ _ ] m′)
   unionWith ∙ (k ↦ v ∷[ l<⁺k ] m) (.k ↦ v′ ∷[ _ ] m′) | (tri≈ _ P.refl _) =
      k ↦ (v ⟨ ∙ ⟩ v′) ∷[ l<⁺k ] unionWith ∙ m m′
   ... | (tri> _ _ k′<⁺k) = k′ ↦ v′ ∷[ _ ] unionWith ∙ (k ↦ v ∷[ _ ] m) m′
```

We will almost certainly need a version where all the indices are ∞, but that's a minor inconvenience.

```
   unionWith′ : ∀ {l u} → (∀ {k} → Op₂ (Value k)) → Op₂ (FiniteMap l u)
   unionWith′ ∙ x y = unionWith ∙ x y
```

Proving a property of `unionWith` using a recursive function will generally require indices to be used in a similar way.

I'm not yet convinced that I won't run into subtleties with more involved use of size indices, but so far I'm impressed by how unintrusive they are. It's certainly less boilerplate than required with the usual Agda termination hacks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the first solution proposed for the [earlier list-merge question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910737/termination-check-on-list-merge) does indeed work here, but only under Agda version 2.3.3+. Here's the full version, with a slightly nicer syntax for ∷.

```
data FiniteMap (l : Key) : Set (k ⊔ v ⊔ ℓ) where
   [] : FiniteMap l
   _∷[_]_ : (kv : KV) → let k = proj₁ kv in l < k → (m : FiniteMap k) → FiniteMap l

-- Split into two definitions to help the termination checker.
unionWith : ∀ {l} → Op₂ Value → Op₂ (FiniteMap l)
unionWith′ : ∀ {l} → Op₂ Value → (kv : KV) → let k = proj₁ kv in l < k → FiniteMap k → Op₁ (FiniteMap l)

unionWith _ [] [] = []
unionWith _ [] m = m
unionWith _ m [] = m
unionWith _⊕_ ((k , v) ∷[ k<l ] m) ((k′ , v′) ∷[ k′<l ] m′) with compare k k′
... | tri< k<k′ _ _ = (k , v) ∷[ k<l ] (unionWith _⊕_ m ((k′ , v′) ∷[ k<k′ ] m′))
... | tri≈ _ k≡k′ _ rewrite P.sym k≡k′ = (k , v ⊕ v′) ∷[ k<l ] (unionWith _⊕_ m m′)
... | tri> _ _ k′<k = (k′ , v′) ∷[ k′<l ] (unionWith′ _⊕_ (k , v) k′<k m m′)

unionWith′ _ (k , v) l<k m [] = (k , v) ∷[ l<k ] m
unionWith′ _⊕_ (k , v) l<k m ((k′ , v′) ∷[ k′<l ] m′) with compare k k′
... | tri< k<k′ _ _ = (k , v) ∷[ l<k ] (unionWith _⊕_ m ((k′ , v′) ∷[ k<k′ ] m′))
... | tri≈ _ k≡k′ _ rewrite P.sym k≡k′ = (k , v ⊕ v′) ∷[ l<k ] (unionWith _⊕_ m m′)
... | tri> _ _ k′<k = (k′ , v′) ∷[ k′<l ] (unionWith′ _⊕_ (k , v) k′<k m m′)
```

Comment: Instead of using `syntax`, you could also use `_∷[_]_` as a name for the `Cons` constructor.

Comment: Oh yes, in this case I can indeed. Thanks. I think that's a bit nicer, so I updated the answer.