# Merge of sorted lists with sized types

Tags: merge, sortedlist, termination, agda

Suppose we have a datatype of sorted lists, with proof-irrelevant sorting witnesses. We'll use Agda's experimental sized types feature, so that we can hopefully get some recursive functions over the datatype to pass Agda's termination checker.

```
{-# OPTIONS --sized-types #-}

open import Relation.Binary
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as P

module ListMerge
   { ℓ}
   (A : Set )
   {_<_ : Rel A ℓ}
   (isStrictTotalOrder : IsStrictTotalOrder _≡_ _<_) where

   open import Level
   open import Size

   data SortedList (l u : A) : {ι : _} → Set ( ⊔ ℓ) where
      [] : {ι : _} → .(l < u) → SortedList l u {↑ ι}
      _∷[_]_ : {ι : _} (x : A) → .(l < x) → (xs : SortedList x u {ι}) → 
               SortedList l u {↑ ι}
```

Now, a classic function one would like to define over such a data structure is `merge`, which takes two sorted lists, and outputs a sorted list containing exactly the elements of the input lists.

```
   open IsStrictTotalOrder isStrictTotalOrder

   merge : ∀ {l u} → SortedList l u → SortedList l u → SortedList l u
   merge xs ([] _) = xs
   merge ([] _) ys = ys
   merge (x ∷[ l<x ] xs) (y ∷[ l<y ] ys) with compare x y
   ... | tri< _ _ _ = x ∷[ l<x ] (merge xs (y ∷[ _ ] ys))
   merge (x ∷[ l<x ] xs) (.x ∷[ _ ] ys) | tri≈ _ P.refl _ = 
      x ∷[ l<x ] (merge xs ys)
   ... | tri> _ _ _ = y ∷[ l<y ] (merge (x ∷[ _ ] xs) ys)
```

This function seems innocuous enough, except that it can be tricky to convince Agda that it's total. Indeed, without any explicit size indices, the function fails to termination-check. One option is to [split the function into two mutually recursive definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910737/termination-check-on-list-merge). This works, but adds a certain amount of redundancy to both the definition and associated proofs.

But equally, I'm not sure whether it is even possible to give size indices explicitly so that `merge` has signature that Agda will accept. [These slides](http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~abel/appsemTalk.ps.gz%E2%80%8E) discuss `mergesort` explicitly; the signature given there suggests that the following should work:

```
   merge′ : ∀ {l u} → {ι : _} → SortedList l u {ι} → 
                      {ι′ : _} → SortedList l u {ι′} → SortedList l u
   merge′ xs ([] _) = xs
   merge′ ([] _) ys = ys
   merge′ (x ∷[ l<x ] xs) (y ∷[ l<y ] ys) with compare x y
   ... | tri< _ _ _ = x ∷[ l<x ] (merge′ xs (y ∷[ _ ] ys))
   merge′ (x ∷[ l<x ] xs) (.x ∷[ _ ] ys) | tri≈ _ P.refl _ = 
      x ∷[ l<x ] (merge′ xs ys)
   ... | tri> _ _ _ = y ∷[ l<y ] (merge' (x ∷[ _ ] xs) ys)
```

Here what we're doing is allowing the inputs to have arbitrary (and different) sizes, and specifying that the output has size ∞.

Unfortunately, with this signature, Agda complains that `.ι != ∞ of type Size`, when checking the body `xs` of the first clause of the definition. I don't claim to understand sized types very well, but I was under the impression that any size ι would unify with ∞. Perhaps the semantics of sized types have changed since those slides were written.

So, is my scenario a use-case for which sized type were intended? If so, how should I should use them? If sized types aren't appropriate here, why does the first version of `merge` above not termination-check, given that [the following does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910737/termination-check-on-list-merge):

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.List
open import Relation.Nullary

merge : List ℕ → List ℕ → List ℕ
merge (x ∷ xs) (y ∷ ys) with x ≤? y
... | yes p = x ∷ merge xs (y ∷ ys)
... | _     = y ∷ merge (x ∷ xs) ys 
merge xs ys = xs ++ ys
```

Comment: First of all, I don't know if it's relevant to the question and I just learn about the existence of Agda. I just want to mention if it is of any help that in Coq the termination of merge need a particular trick which is described for example in http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/GeneralRec.html

Comment: You can make your `merge′` work if you rebuild `xs` and `ys` with larger size, something like `promote : ∀ {l u i} → SortedList l u {i} → SortedList l u {∞}`.

Comment: I did wonder about that (although it seemed a bit crazy, and still does :). I guess one would establish that promote is essentially `id` and that might keep the impact on proofs manageable. Thanks, I'll have a look at this when I get a chance.

Comment: I've had chance to experiment with your suggestion, using the `FiniteMap` type and `unionWith` function [I asked about before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216389/termination-check-on-unionwith). It seems to work pretty well, so I've added a new answer to my previous question, based on sized types. As for this question, I would suggest promoting your comment to answer; that might make it more visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly enough, your first version is actually correct. I mentioned that Agda enables few extra rules considering `Size`, one of them being `↑ ∞ ≡ ∞`. By the way, you can confirm it via:

```
↑inf : ↑ ∞ ≡ ∞
↑inf = refl
```

Well, this led me to investigate what the other rules are. I found the rest of them inside Andreas Abel's slides on sized types (can be found [here](http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~abel/talkAIM2008Sendai.pdf)):

- `↑ ∞ ≡ ∞`
- `i ≤ ↑ i ≤ ∞`
- `T {i} <: T {↑ i} <: T {∞}`

The `<:` relation is the subtyping relation, which you might know from object oriented languages. There's also a rule associated with this relation, the *subsumption* rule:

```
Γ ⊢ x : A   Γ ⊢ A <: B
────────────────────── (sub)
      Γ ⊢ x : B
```

So, if you have a value `x` of type `A` and you know that `A` is a subtype of `B`, you can treat `x` as being of type `B` as well. This seemed strange, because following the subtyping rule for sized types, you should be able to treat a value of type `SortedList l u {ι}` as `SortedList l u`.

So I did bit of a digging and found this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/detail?id=701). And indeed, the problem is just that Agda doesn't correctly recognize the size and the rule doesn't fire. All I needed to do was to rewrite the definition of `SortedList` to:

```
data SortedList (l u : A) : {ι : Size} → Set ( ⊔ ℓ) where
  -- ...
```

And that's it!

---

As an addendum, here's the code I used for testing:

```
data ℕ : {ι : _} → Set where         -- does not work
-- data ℕ : {ι : Size} → Set where   -- works
  zero : ∀ {ι} →         ℕ {↑ ι}
  suc  : ∀ {ι} → ℕ {ι} → ℕ {↑ ι}

test : ∀ {ι} → ℕ {ι} → ℕ
test n = n
```

Comment: Oh. I had indeed interpreted the intended rules as subsumption/subsumption, but assumed I'd misunderstood something when it didn't work. Well, that's certainly good news (and thanks for putting in the time to discover this). I'll update my other answer.